# How to renew an authorization token in background with Auth0 in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, nuxt.js, auth0

For the platform I'm currently working on, my employer decided to outsource authentication to [Auth0](https://auth0.com/).

We managed to get the login and logout flows to work, by opening a hosted page on Auth0 and redirecting to our platform after succesful login / logout.

Upon a successful login with an email & password, Auth0 returns a response in the following format :

```json
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IlEwWTFRemREUlRW...",
  "expires_in": "86400",
  "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IlEwWTFRemREUlRWRk9V...",
  "scope": "openid email",
  "state": "my-custom-state",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

According to [the official Auth0 documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/silent-authentication), Auth0 allows two method for renewing an existing authorization token :

- silent authentication requests, for tokens that have not expired yet
- a silent token request in a hidden iframe, for tokens that have expired

---

## Silent authentication requests

The documentation tells me I should to a get request to the following URL :

```
https://████████████████████/authorize
    ?response_type=id_token token&
    client_id=...&
    redirect_uri=...&
    state=...&
    scope=openid...&
    nonce=...&
    audience=...&
    response_mode=...&
    prompt=none
```

When I open this URL in any tab of my browser, I am indeed correctly redirected to the `redirect_uri`, if this `redirect_uri` is listed in the Auth0 config. And a new token is added to the `url` after an `#`.

I am, however, unable to get this to work with XHR, either from the backend (Node.js / Nuxt) or the frontend (Vue / Nuxt). When I try doing this from the frontend, my browser complains that this resource didn't set CORS headers. When I try doing this from the backend, I can't find a way to pass my credentials to the URL.

---

## Renewing expired tokens

I can't find any code examples of demos for how to renew expired tokens without the use of the [auth0.js library](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.js), which I'd rather not use if possible.

And when I try using their demo for the auth0.js library after installing it locally, I can't even get a simple login to work after filling in all these fields :

[image]

This is the error I'm getting :

```json
{
  "original": {
    "error": "request_error",
    "error_description": "{\"crossDomain\":true,\"method\":\"POST\",\"url\":\"https://████████████████████/co/authenticate\"}"
  },
  "code": "request_error",
  "description": "{\"crossDomain\":true,\"method\":\"POST\",\"url\":\"https://████████████████████/co/authenticate\"}",
  "error": "request_error",
  "error_description": "{\"crossDomain\":true,\"method\":\"POST\",\"url\":\"https://████████████████████/co/authenticate\"}"
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to properly implement a refresh in blackground, either of expired of non-expired Auth tokens?

---

### UPDATE

I managed to get one step further, by...

1. porting the `SilentAuthenticationHandler` from `Auth0.js` to my project
2. Commenting out one line in the `SilentAuthenticationHandler` to prevent the browser from freaking out if the `/authorize` endpoint is on a different domain
3. Creating an instance of `SilentAuthenticationHandler` with an url that has `response_mode` `web_message` and a value for `postMessageOrigin` that corresponds with my `audience`
4. Calling the `login` method on `SilentAuthenticationHandler, with` usePostMessage`set to`true`, to open the` /authorize` endpoint in a hidden iframe
5. Parsing the hash in the URL of the `callback` page passed as a `redirect_uri` and then using `Window.parent.postMessage(parsedParams, '*')` to send it back to the main window

After taking all of these 5 steps, I finally get my new access token & id token.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to update my Nuxt with these new credentials. I looked for inspiration in the `@nuxtjs/auth` package, but the best I could come up with, is something like this :

```js
this.$auth.setUserToken(token);
```

I tried combining this with eg. `fetchUser` & a `setUser`, but no matter what I try, it keep ***ing up my session and trigger a `400` error upon reload.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to implement auth flows and token renewal by yourself? Are you using any library or doing everything manually?

Comment: If you are using SPA in browser, you should consider using "Authorization code with PKCE" flow as the most secure one at the moment.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh : As I mentioned in my question, our platform runs on [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/). We do use [a Nuxt plugin](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/auth0.html) to simpify the login and logout, but I could not find any info on how to renew my token. But you're right : I should probably have logged an issue on their Github page first... I will do that now!

Comment: @VladimirSerykh : I've been looking into the Nuxt plugin & the Auth0.js library, which got me one step further. I now actually do manage to get my access token, but I can't find a way to update my Nuxt with it!

Answer (score 3):

You have to do it by via a web redirect since Authorization Servers won't set CORS headers for Ajax requests. If it was allowed there would be more scope for malicious browser tabs to get tokens for your API.

The standard technique for an SPA is to use a hidden iframe and this is tricky to code. The [oidc client library](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) has a widely used mature solution that I always use.

If it helps I have some resources that show how to integrate the library and do silent token renewal in the recommended manner:

- [Renewal Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/tree/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth)
- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/24/user-sessions-and-token-renewal/)

Comment: I was in fact planning to experiment with a hidden iframe tomorrow. THank you for helping me on my way!

Comment: I got one step further... but still not where I want to be!

Comment: @JohnSlegers have you tried with the hidden iframe? We are facing the same issue with nuxt-auth and auth0 refresh token.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use authentication in nuxt app on my experience the best thing that you can use is [nuxt auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) module

it handels a lots of codings and it's sooo easy to use and understand also published by official nuxt site

if you use that you can logout with:

```
this.$auth.logout(/* .... */)
```

Comment: I am already using that module. I'm actually already using it to log in and out. Unfortunately, I'm unable to figure out how to use it to renew a token...

Comment: for get the new token use `this.$auth.fetchUser()`

Comment: @ Ali Hosseini : As far as I can tell, based on the code, `fetchUser` just fetches user info based on the token in the localStorage. So I just do `fetchUser`, the plugin just gets the user info for the token already in there. If I first do `SetUserToken`, and then to a `fetchUser`, I would expect to get the expected result. Instead, I get a `400` error.